# Maven и Eclipse - установка и настройка

Tags: eclipse, maven

Скачала мавен (zip) с сайта, попыталась запустить jar - ничего не произошло. Как установить мавен и что делать с загадочным "прописать PATH"? Где найти пошаговое руководство по установке мавена, желательно со скринами и стрелочками, куда тыкать? (для чайников, которые это делают впервые и никогда раньше о таких финтах даже не слышали)

И как его впоследствии привязать к эклипсу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поддержка maven в Eclipse плагинами делается. И нет необходимости её отдельно ставить самому.

1. Открываем Eclipse IDE.
2. Жмём Help -> Install New Software...
3. Жмём Add button.
4. Вводим "M2Eclipse" и путь.
   "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases".
5. OK.

Или

1. Открыть Eclipse.
2. Help -> Eclipse Marketplace.
3. Ищем по слову Maven.
4. Жмём "Install" напротив "Maven Integration for Eclipse".
5. Дальше по инструкции.

Если же вы, всё же, хотите установить Maven ручками, а потом использовать, то :

1. m2e плагин поставить по инструкции выше.
2. Устанавливаем [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/windows-prerequisites.html).
3. Не забываем в PATH системы добавить путь до установки, чтоб можно было выполнять `mvn -version` и другие команды.
4. В Eclipse выбрать Window->Preference->Maven->Installations и там Add нажать и указать путь до места, куда вы установили Maven.

Comment: я скачала мавен(лежит в папке на рабочем столе), попыталась запустить jar файл, но ничего не происходит, что с мавеном делать дальше? для меня в этом месте главная непонятка и как прописывать path тоже не ясно(никогда этого не делала раньше)

Comment: часть с эклипсом более чем понятна, за нее спасибо. не понятна только сама установка мавена(что где должно находиться, как его заставить работать и где чего прописывать)

Comment: Какой jar файл? о_О Отсюда качали ? http://apache-mirror.rbc.ru/pub/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.zip

Comment: проблема решилась, была загвоздка с прописанным ранее JAVA_HOME - была указана более старая версия, стоявшая на машине 4 года назад... после обновления в пути информации о версии все заработало